# How to prevent drawing XNA component when it is off-screen?

Tags: c#, performance, xna, drawablegamecomponent

I'm making a 2d game in XNA.
When using drawable game components which one is better for performance?

1.When a component is not onscreen remove it from the components list and when its onscreen add it.

2.When its offscreen dont run its draw function (by using an "awake" bool field and an
if statement around everything in the draw function)

I'm using method 2 at the moment and it works fine. Its handy cus the draworder of components wont change (if I remove and re-add them it will, and I'll need more code to manage that)
In fact it just occured to me that if its not in the components list it wont update and I'll need something else to keep track of whether its onscreen or not..

Also I dont have the fancy version of visual studio with the profiler so I'm just asking here what do people think from their experience

Comment: You don't need an expensive profiler to determine which is faster in a test `Stopwatch` is good enough for that.  The profiler will help explain *why* one is faster than the other (namely, what parts of this algorithm are slow, what's consuming the most memory, do I need to bother optimizing this section, etc.).

Comment: I would belive choice 2 would be faster.

Comment: How many `DrawableGameComponent`s do you use?  If you are using a lot of instances of it, you are probably mis-using it.

Comment: @Guye  Are you concerned about CPU performance or GPU performance by this question?

Comment: @Seth  - Yes I'm using *a lot* of drawable game components. Each block that makes up the walls is a drawable game component.. Could you please explain yourself a bit more?

Comment: @ Steve.. I'm aiming to have it run smoothly on low-end laptops so I guess I'm more concerned about cpu, as most laptops will have very poor gpus and also their cpus tend to overheat.. in fact a lot of indie games make my laptop meltdown! (minecraft and FTL being 2 that spring to mind)

Comment: @GuyeIncognito Yes, I'll elaborate in an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A sometimes overlooked concept of CPU performance while using SpriteBatch is how you go about batching your sprites. And using drawable game component doesn't lend itself easily to efficiently batching sprites.

Basically, The GPU drawing the sprites is not slow & the CPU organizing all the sprites into a batch is not slow. The slow part is when the CPU has to communicate to the GPU what it needs to draw (sending it the batch info). This CPU to GPU communication **does not happen** when you call spriteBatch.Draw(). It happens when you call spriteBatch.End(). So the low hanging fruit to efficiency is calling spriteBatch.End() less often. (of course this means calling Begin() less often too). Also, use spriteSortMode.Imediate very sparingly because it immediately causes the CPU to send each sprites info to the GPU (slow)).

So if you call Begin() & End() in each game component class, and have many components, you are costing yourself a lot of time unnecessarily and you will probably save more time coming up with a better batching scheme than worrying about offscreen sprites.

Aside: The GPU automatically ignores offscreen sprites from its pixel shader anyway. So culling offscreen sprites on the CPU won't save GPU time...

Comment: Thanks a lot! very informative.. Also, just fyi, my game has procedurally generated levels made of rooms. I did a stress test with 140 rooms before I had anything coded for performance and it was hellah slow. I then made it so only the room you are currently in is drawn (method 2 in my post) And performance went back to perfect, in the light of your answer that was all cpu, which makes sense as this in running on a craptop which struggles with visual studio! :)  I think I will follow your advice and re-architect a bit to make my begin and end statements hold a lot more

Comment: I would like to say that just because you're using drawablegamecomponents, that doesn't mean you can't use the same spritebatch.begin(). If you situate your base.draw inside the spritebatch, you can call begin from your main Game file, then do all your drawing in your components, then spritebatch.end in the Game file again.

Comment: @TopHatHacker  I thought of mentioning that but didn't when I realized that if there are some 3d drawable components and some 2d components, then that would not work.