# Does drawing outside of screen bounds affect performance

Tags: c#, performance, xna

In my 2D game I have large map, and I scroll around it (like in Age of Empires).

On draw I draw all the elements (which are textures/Images).  Some of them are on the screen, but most of them are not (because you see about 10% of the map).

Does XNA know not to draw them by checking that the destination rectangle won't fall on the screen?

Or should I manually check it and avoid drawing them at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must manually account for this, and it will largely effect the performance of the game as it grows, this is otherwise known as culling. Culling is not done just because drawing stuff off screen reduces performance, it is because calling `Draw` that many extra times is slow. Anything you don't need to update that is out of the viewport should be excluded too. You can see more about how you can do this and how `SpriteBatch` handles this [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9277/optimizing-an-xna-2d-game).

Comment: Why he doesn't do it ?

Comment: In the link you gave me it's written that i need to cull only if i have more sprites than he can handle in single batch, but it doesnt answer the question whether he draws them or not ...

Comment: It doesn't. It will pass the data to the GPU and by default, it will cull what is off screen. Drawing outside the bounds of the screen in theory is not something that reduces performance, but if you are making thousands of `Draw` calls to the spritebatch each frame, then you are exceeding limits and it will kill your framerate.

Comment: What @Sarkilas said, Sorry if I worded the answer wrong. It isn't because you are drawing stuff offscreen, but because more `Draw()` calls must be executed.

Comment: You didn't word it wrong, Cyral, I was just clarifying to OopsUser.

Comment: draw only visible tiles and sprites. i forgot to remove missed bullets in my SHMUP, so when i put game on streess test it start to lag after 10 minutes because it's was still drawing bullets that were miles and miles out of screen.

Answer (score 7):

A sometimes overlooked concept of CPU performance while using `SpriteBatch` is how you go about batching your sprites. And using drawable game component doesn't lend itself easily to efficiently batching sprites.

Basically, The GPU drawing the sprites is not slow & the CPU organizing all the sprites into a batch is not slow. The slow part is when the CPU has to communicate to the GPU what it needs to draw (sending it the batch info). This CPU to GPU communication **does not happen** when you call `spriteBatch.Draw()`. It happens when you call `spriteBatch.End()`. So the low hanging fruit to efficiency is calling `spriteBatch.End()` less often. (of course this means calling `Begin()` less often too). Also, use `spriteSortMode.Immediate` very sparingly because it immediately causes the CPU to send each sprites info to the GPU (slow)).

So if you call `Begin()` & `End()` in each game component class, and have many components, you are costing yourself a lot of time unnecessarily and you will probably save more time coming up with a better batching scheme than worrying about offscreen sprites.

Aside: The GPU automatically ignores offscreen sprites from its pixel shader anyway. So culling offscreen sprites on the CPU won't save GPU time.

Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14503316/2498113).